# Increasing the default number of posts in custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I need to increase the number of items I can show on my page using Custom Post Type and [ACF plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Currently I have 26 items with tendency to grow, but it only shows 10 on my page. Here is part of the code:

```
<?php $args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_type' => 'products',
'order' =>'ASC',
 ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess ACF is Advanced Custom Fields and CPT custom post type. I'm not used to these acronyms.

Seeing -1 I guess you want to show all of your 26 items.

change `numberposts` for `posts_per_page`

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'products', 
'order' =>'ASC',
 );
?>
```